# Bidirectional Mercurial merges

Tags: mercurial, merge, bidirectional

Given two repositories: a) myrepo-1_0 and b) myrepo-feature which was cloned off version 1.0.5 from myrepo-1_0.

After myrepo-feature was created, we checked in changesets B1 and B2 to myrepo-feature.  Then we checked in A5, A6, A7 to myrepo-1_0.

We merged A5/A6/A7 to myrepo-feature.  Then we additionally added B3 to myrepo-feature.

Can we now do a merge from myrepo-feature back to myrepo-1_0?  This merge would effectively just merge changesets B1/B2/B3 back to myrepo-1_0.

We've never done this type of 'bidirectional merging'.  Wasn't sure if this was encouraged or not.  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we now do a merge from myrepo-feature back to myrepo-1_0?

Yes, you can do this merge

> Wasn't sure if this was encouraged or not

Even if not encouraged, it's possible and fit in many workflows